# string sequence in code blocks causes error on save

Tags: bug, status-norepro

If I try put the string
`DECLARE @origUserName` `varchar(max)` as a single continuous line in a code block (either using backticks or prepend with 4 spaces) then I get an error on submit when I try save the question or answer. Note that I had to break it up into 2 separate code blocks to save this question.

It's odd because I can put

```
DECLARE @origUserName varchar
```

in a code block.
and I can put

```
DECLARE origUserName varchar(max)
```

in a code block and save. so it seems to be the combination of @ and ( ) somehow that is causing the issue but neither one individually.

( I verified I saw the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome so it's not some browser specific / cookie issue )

Comment: What error do you get on submit?

Comment: if you add an answer and try save it with the string as a single line in a code block you'll see, but its basically a red message that says error on submit of answer/question

Comment: No repro on MSE with IE11....

Comment: hmm, I can't even paste the text just plain into a comment and save it. "An error occurred during comment submission"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most likely something on your end getting freaked out by SQL. We've heard reports of some proxies/firewall software causing issues like this before. Unfortunately, we have no control over that.

Comment: hmmm. that's an interesting theory. I suppose I'm behind mcafee web gateway and some other things.

Comment: DECLARE @origUserName varchar(max)

Comment: yeah, ok, that pretty much proves it because over HTTPS I can post it without issue so I'm assuming it's inspecting the traffic over HTTP but can't do so over HTTPS. thanks, was really puzzling.